# KnockoutJS and Jquery how to fill combo dynamically

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a form that uses 2 combos. The first combo is filled when the form is loaded and the second one is filled from server (ajax) depending on the first combo selection.

Here is the ajax code for filling my `supervisors` combo:

```
// here go and get employee supervisors
var cboSupervisor = $('#cboAuthorizer');
cboSupervisor.html('');

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Content("~/Employee/GetEmployeeSupervisors")/',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        employeeId: ui.item.employeeId
    }),
    success: function(data) {

        if (data.success) {
            $.each(data.data, function() {
                cboSupervisor.append($("<option />").val(this.SupervisorId).text(this.SupervisorName));
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I have my `knockoutjs` model but didn't work the `data-bind` for this combo and I guess is because of the dynamic loading of the combo.

```
<select id="cboAuthorizer" class="form-control" data-bind="value: exitPass.authorizer">
</select>
```

My knockout model looks like this:

```
var jsonPass = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model.ExitPass, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, jsonSettings));

var ExitPass = function(exitPass) {
    var self = this;

    self.incidentId = ko.observable(exitPass.IncidentId || 0);
    self.employeeId = ko.observable(exitPass.EmployeeId || 0);
    self.employerId = ko.observable(exitPass.EmployerId || 0);
    self.employerDesc = ko.observable(exitPass.EmployerDesc);
    self.employeeNumber = ko.observable(exitPass.EmployeeNumber);
    self.employeeName = ko.observable(exitPass.EmployeeName);
    self.createdByName = ko.observable(exitPass.CreatedByName);
    self.incidentDate = ko.observable(exitPass.IncidentDate);
    self.incidentCode = ko.observable(exitPass.IncidentCode);
    self.incidentCodeDesc = ko.observable(exitPass.IncidentCodeDesc);
    self.incidentTypeId = ko.observable(exitPass.IncidentTypeId || 0);
    self.incidentType = ko.observable(exitPass.IncidentType);
    self.permitType = ko.observable(exitPass.PermitType);
    self.outHour = ko.observable(exitPass.OutHour);
    self.inHour = ko.observable(exitPass.InHour);
    self.place = ko.observable(exitPass.Place);
    self.subject = ko.observable(exitPass.Subject);
    self.securityStaffId = ko.observable(exitPass.SecurityStaffId || 0);
    self.authorizer = ko.observable(exitPass.Authorizer || 0);
    self.notes = ko.observable(exitPass.Notes);
};
```

> Any clue on how can I solve this? Do I have to create an array or something so I can assign that to the combo and get the value binded? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: combo will work but you haven't specified `options` . options will take the list of you combo

Comment: How can I create a knockoutjs list that is filled from my ajax request?

Comment: check the answer provided a sample version of it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing like this

**View Model:**

```
    var vm=function(){

    this.Combo1Array=ko.observableArray();
    function(exitPass) {
    var self = this;
    //your observable specific to function
    }

    $.ajax({
       //other stuff
       success: function(data) {
       if (data.success) {
        self.Combo1Array(data.data) // fill the observableArray here
           }
         }
       });

    }
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

**View:**

```
<select id="cboAuthorizer" class="form-control" data-bind="options:$root.Combo1Array,optionsValue:'SupervisorId',optionsText:'SupervisorName',value:exitPass.authorizer">
</select>
```

$root or $data anything used based on the scope

options Documentation is clearly given **[here in ko docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)**

Comment: How do I fill the observableArray?

Comment: data.data is having list of SupervisorId and SupervisorName pairs right ? if so just assign directly the list

Comment: Worked like a charm!! I have a other question similar to this, I will post a in a new question and let you know appreciate it

Comment: I can't ask more than 6 question in 24 hours :(, but basically is: can I assing a value manually like this: appViewModel.exitPass.employeeId(123);

Comment: no you can't do that . if you want to pass a static value keep in `=ko.observable(x || 123)` like that . when x is undefined you get you dummy value assigned .

Comment: but there is way you can achieve like this check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/22372/